# Card bots are not Replying

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have tried to integrate a card bot with teams, but bot is not replying also in bot emulator ,while same bot is replying in https://dev.botframework.com/bots/  and bot service of azure.code is same as BotBuilder-Sample inside that cards-Adaptivecards.Only change i have done is 
`// Create chat bot and listen to messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "628d8adc-3196-405d-87f6-d94ebfd3c511",
    appPassword: "gqihkQISB5~crWKP5463|}_"
});`  harded coded appId and password.

> The Bot State API is deprecated. Please refer to aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage. And error ocurred Error: GET to 'b23cc4c1.ngrok.io/v3/botstate/emulator/users/default-user'; failed: [402] Payment Required at Request._callback (C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\card-adaptive\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:559:46) at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\card-adaptive\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22) at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)

Manifest:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.2/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.2",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "89d4a972-fad6-41ce-9f0f-aaae569cd6ed",
    "packageName": "Hotel-finder",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Lalit",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "contoso96x96.png",
        "outline": "contoso20x20.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "Hotel App ",
        "full": "Hotel finder"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "hotel finder",
        "full": "Bot find hotels"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "628d8adc-3196-405d-87f6-d94ebfd3c511",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}
```

Comment: "bot is not replying also in bot emulator" : what error do you have in the emulator?

Comment: The Bot State API is deprecated.  Please refer to https://aka.ms/I6swrh for details on how to replace with your own storage.
And error ocurred Error: GET to 'https://b23cc4c1.ngrok.io/v3/botstate/emulator/users/default-user' failed: [402] Payment Required
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\card-adaptive\node_modules\botbuilder\lib\bots\ChatConnector.js:559:46)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\WittyParrot\Documents\card-adaptive\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)

Comment: You have provided no useful information for anyone to help you with this issue.

Comment: Please tell ... what information should I provide

Comment: your code would be a good start

Comment: Code is sample code of BotBuilder-Sample inside this cards-Adaptivecards....Only change i have done is                                       
 // Create chat bot and listen to messages
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: "628d8adc-3196-405d-87f6-d94ebfd3c511",
    appPassword: "gqihkQISB5~crWKP5463|}_"
}); /// i have hard coded the appId and password...

Comment: Do you get a 402 Payment Required error with any other bots or web apps?

Comment: yes i get same problem in other bot too...but it gos when i put appid and password but in card-adaptive it still prevails...

Answer (score 0):

Per [Adaptive Cards for Bot Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots):

> Skype and Microsoft Teams are not yet supported in the current preview, but we're working on it! Please see the Channel Status section below for details.

And:

> Microsoft Teams:  Full support coming soon

In the meantime, Adaptive Cards will not display in Microsoft Teams.  The 402 error sounds like a different issue.

Comment: Thanks for Answer...but i got same problem in BotBuilder-sample inside that cards-RichCards...This is also not replying in teams..

Comment: Or suggest some working sample which will work with teams....today i has demo with client...